# How to get the task Id from the variable Local?

Tags: activiti

I am update the Task in Activiti by using the following code.

```
@Service
@Log4j
public class TicketUpdateService {
    @Autowired
    TaskService taskService;

    @Autowired
    RuntimeService runtimeService;

    @Transactional
    public BaseDto updateTicket(TicketHistoryDto historyDto) {
              String taskId = historyDto.getTaskId();
              runtimeService.setVariable(historyDto.getExecutionId(), "STATE",
                historyDto.getTicketState());

    if (historyDto.getNotes() != null
                && historyDto.getNotes().trim().length() > 0) {
            log.info(" Setting the notes");
            taskService.setVariableLocal(taskId, "notes", historyDto
                    .getNotes().trim());
            ticket.setDescription(historyDto.getNotes().trim());
        }
        /** Update the Ticket Status */
        if (historyDto.getTicketStatusInfo() != null) {
            log.info(" Setting the Ticket Status as  "
                    + historyDto.getTicketStatusInfo());
            taskService.setVariableLocal(taskId, "ticketStatus",
                    historyDto.getTicketStatusInfo());
        }
         taskService.complete(taskId);
}  }
```

I need to get the task using the task variable . For this purpose I am using the following code

```
@Service
@Log4j
public class TicketActivitiServiceImpl{

     @Autowired
     private TaskService taskService;

     public List<Task> getTasks(){
        TaskQuery activitiQuery = taskService.createTaskQuery();

        // I can able to get the Task based Process variable 
        if (searchDto.getCategory() != null && searchDto.getCategory() > 0l) {
            log.info("Category Id : " + searchDto.getCategory());
            activitiQuery.processVariableValueEquals("category",
                    searchDto.getCategory());
        }
        if (searchDto.getSubCategory() != null
                && searchDto.getSubCategory() > 0L) {
            log.info("Sub Category Id : " + searchDto.getSubCategory());
            activitiQuery.processVariableValueEquals("subCategory",
                    searchDto.getSubCategory());

        }
        //  I am not able to get the task information after including the following code 
        //  I need the task based on Task Variable also 
       if (searchDto.getTicketStatus() != null
                && !"".equals(searchDto.getTicketStatus().trim())) {
            log.info("Ticket status : " + searchDto.getTicketStatus());
            activitiQuery.includeTaskLocalVariables()
                    .taskVariableValueEqualsIgnoreCase("ticketStatus",
                            searchDto.getTicketStatus().trim());

        }
        activitiQuery.taskCandidateOrAssigned("" + searchDto.getUserId());
        activitiQuery.orderByTaskCreateTime().desc();
        List<Task> taskList = activitiQuery.list();

    }
}
```

I need to get the Running task based on Task variables and also Process variable.  I am able to get the task based on Process variable but it fails to get the task for the task variable

Answer (score 0):

I include the variable as a task variable. When the complete the task all the task variable is moved to ACT_HI_TASKINST table. But the query try to fetch the value from ACT_RU_VARIABLE Table. so  It wont available for the next task.

So I replaced the the following code

```
taskService.setVariableLocal(taskId, "ticketStatus", historyDto.getTicketStatusInfo());
```

with this line of code

```
taskService.setVariable(taskId, "ticketStatus", historyDto.getTicketStatusInfo());
```

It insert the variable as a process variable.not as a task variable. It is available throughout the process

Answer (score 0):

Note that variables can be set local for a given execution (remember a process instance consists of a tree of executions). The variable will only be visible on that execution, and not higher in the tree of executions. This can be useful if data shouldn’t be propagated to the process instance level, or the variable has a new value for a certain path in the process instance (for example when using parallel paths).

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#apiVariables